# How do I sort an array of objects based on another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of a dynamic sizing that changes its order based on what is last selected to position 0 of the array. Problem is I want to keep the original order of the array.

In order to do that, I have created an additional variable that is set to the original sorting of the array. Although some of the values of the array might change after the selecting of the item, the name property never does. I want to use this fact to sort the new array to the original position.

```
let keepRateOrder = rates.sort((a, b) => {  
        return prevRates.indexOf(a.name) - prevRates.indexOf(b.name);
      });


const rates = [
{name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63 ...},
{name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23 ...},
{name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33 ...}
]


const prevRates = [
{name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23 ...},
{name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63 ...},
{name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33 ...}
]
```

Comment: @p.s.w.g keepRatesOrder is incorrect, my problem is just sorting rates to the same order prevRates was in. prevRates is just a copy of the rates array before it was changed. I would just like to return it to its original order.

Comment: @user7659932 Which one is the unique key? The `name`?

Comment: @NikKyriakides yes, the rest of values are subject to change

Comment: @CertainPerformance there is an example of what prevRates might look like, the only difference between the two is the order and some of the other properties not listed might be different.

Comment: Why not have a variable point to the selected rate? Somewhere isChoosen is being set for each one every time there's an update, instead it could just update a variable, or set it to null if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). In the following example the sort will put `Mail` first as per the `prevRates` array:

```js
const rates = [
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63},
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23},
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33}
];

const prevRates = [
  {name: 'Mail'},
  {name: 'UPS'},
  {name: 'FedEx'},
];

let keepRateOrder = rates.sort((a, b) => {
  return prevRates.findIndex(p => p.name === a.name) - prevRates.findIndex(p => p.name === b.name);
});

console.log(keepRateOrder);
```

You could accomplish the same thing with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) if you [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) first. This leads to somewhat cleaner code:

```js
const rates = [
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63},
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23},
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33}
];

const prevRates = [
  {name: 'Mail'},
  {name: 'UPS'},
  {name: 'FedEx'},
].map(x => x.name);

let keepRateOrder = rates.sort((a, b) => {
  return prevRates.indexOf(a.name) - prevRates.indexOf(b.name);
});

console.log(keepRateOrder);
```

And here's one more solution just using a hash of the original indexes, created using [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight):

```js
const rates = [
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63},
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23},
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33}
]

const prevRates = [
  {name: 'Mail'},
  {name: 'UPS'},
  {name: 'FedEx'},
].reduceRight((a, x, i) => (a[x.name] = i, a), {});

let keepRateOrder = rates.sort((a, b) => {
  return prevRates[a.name] - prevRates[b.name];
});

console.log(keepRateOrder);
```

Since you said that items may be added or removed from the original array, note that all of the above solutions will place new items first (since their index in the `prevRates` array will be returned as `-1`). If you want new items to appear at the end, you'll need to do something like this:

```js
const rates = [
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63},
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23},
  {name:'Foo'},
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33},
];

const prevRates = [
  {name: 'Mail'},
  {name: 'UPS'},
  {name: 'FedEx'},
].map(x => x.name);

let keepRateOrder = rates.sort((a, b) => {
  const aIndex = prevRates.indexOf(a.name);
  const bIndex = prevRates.indexOf(b.name);
  return (aIndex === -1 ? Number.MAX_VALUE : aIndex) - (bIndex === -1 ? Number.MAX_VALUE : bIndex);
});

console.log(keepRateOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

First use `.map` to transform the `prevRates` into an array of just the `name` properties, and then you can use `.sort` based on that array of names:

```js
const prevRates = [
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23 },
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63 },
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33 }
];
const rates = [
  {name:'UPS', isChoosen:true, cost:63 },
  {name:'Mail', isChoosen:false, cost:23 },
  {name:'FedEx', isChoosen:false, cost:33 }
];

const prevRatesNames = prevRates.map(({ name }) => name);
rates.sort((a, b) => (
  prevRatesNames.indexOf(a.name) - prevRatesNames.indexOf(b.name)
));
console.log(rates);
```

Remember that `.sort` sorts *in-place* - if you do

```
let keepRateOrder = rates.sort...
```

then `keepRateOrder` will just be another reference to the `rates` array. If you want a copy, rather than mutating the original `rates` array, then you'll have to shallow copy `rates` first:

```
const keepRateOrder = rates.slice().sort...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a new property to each item to track the original index, `originalIndex`. Sort using that when you want the original order back, avoids the extra copy. Assuming that's what you want to do!